# Heroku at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" Spring App

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, heroku, heroku-cli

I had a deploy this my api in Heroku but not working my repository is open.

the route "login" exists but is not working.

link to repository: https://github.com/Luciannodev/HelpDesk

```
2023-01-25T07:31:18.918471+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Starting process with command \`java -jar -Dserver.port=44402 build/libs/\*.jar\`
2023-01-25T07:31:19.979380+00:00 app\[web.1\]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2023-01-25T07:31:19.984194+00:00 app\[web.1\]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2023-01-25T07:31:20.219825+00:00 app\[web.1\]: no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/HelpDesk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
2023-01-25T07:31:20.359733+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Process exited with status 1
2023-01-25T07:31:20.411343+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-01-25T07:31:20.415394+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-01-25T07:31:24.466209+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Starting process with command \`java -jar -Dserver.port=40705 build/libs/\*.jar\`
2023-01-25T07:31:25.477403+00:00 app\[web.1\]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2023-01-25T07:31:25.482876+00:00 app\[web.1\]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2023-01-25T07:31:25.638311+00:00 app\[web.1\]: no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/HelpDesk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
2023-01-25T07:31:25.767475+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Process exited with status 1
2023-01-25T07:31:25.828321+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-01-25T07:31:37.011794+00:00 heroku\[router\]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ludev-helpdesk-prod.herokuapp.com request_id=add4197e-4d6a-4647-a03b-6763a6e38c90 fwd="177.62.242.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Have you read the error? `2023-01-25T07:31:25.638311+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/HelpDesk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar` is pretty clear. Apparently you didn't use the SPring Boot plugin to create the jar.

Comment: but spring boot plugin are in gradle.build.

Comment: But did you use it, or did you decided to do some export jar from your IDE. If you didn't use gradle to build the jar there would be nothing in there.